# p5.js global and instance mode confusion

Tags: p5.js

I have two p5 sketches, and I want to use them in the same space of a website. So that after clicking a button, the sketches switch. So I made three different files. The first two, are the sketches, and they are wrapped in a function (instance mode). The third sketch is a code written in global mode, because It has the information that loads a button right when the website is first accesed, and it has the information containing what the button is supposed to do: call the other sketches. 
The code looks like this:

```javascript
var playing = false;


var button;

function setup() {
  var col = color(185,185,185,150);
  button = createButton('Play');
  button.position(20,20);
  button.parent('black');
  button.style("background-color", col);
  button.style("padding", "10px 20px");
  button.style("font-size", "14px");

  button.mousePressed(toggleCanvas); // attach button listener

}

function mousePressed() {
}


function toggleCanvas() {
  if (playing) {

          if(myp5r){
                         myp5r.remove();
                         runSketch();
                         button.html('Stop');

                         }else{

                              runSketch();
                              button.html('Stop'); 

                               }
 }else {
       if(myp5){myp5.remove();
                     stopSketch();
                     button.html('Play');
}else{
    stopSketch();
    button.html('Play');}
  }
  playing = !playing;
}
```

I have been warned, to not mix global and instance mode, although my "common sense" says that it is ok to use a global mode for the button. Because I want it to be loading first, along with the page. 
I noticed that weird things happen, though. Like, I get a blank space added beneath the footer, it looks horrible. And, even more worse, button is not appearing in the correct spot in the site. I already ckecked that css has position:relative for example. And the design works in localhost, but not in the site.

Comment: So you were told to not mix global and instance mode (by me), chose to ignore that advice, and now weird thing are happening? That is exactly why I told you to not mix global and instance mode. Anyway, when I try to run your code I get errors in the console. Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, or better yet a link to a CodePen.

Comment: BTW, the footer issue did get fixed by changing all sketches to instance mode

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Mixing global and instance mode is just confusing the whole thing.

Comment: This might be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). If you want to run a p5 animation while your main sketch loads, the way to do it is not combining global and instance modes, it's avoiding `preload()` and loading assets from `setup()` (`loadImage`), then choosing which scene to show conditionally in `draw()`, or using callbacks.